# LINQ two datatables join

Tags: c#, linq, join, foreach, datatable

I am stuck with this problem.
I am able to solve this problem by using foreach but there has to be a better solution for this.

I have a two datatables.
First has a column named "Por"
Second has two column named "FirstPor" and "LastPor".
My goals is to use LINQ for creating a new datatable depending on condition like this.

```
foreach ( DataRow row in FirstDatatable.Rows )
{
    foreach ( DataRow secondRow in SecondDatatable.Rows )
    {
       if ( row["Por"] >= secondRow["FirstPor"] && row["Por"] <= secondRow["LastPor"] )
            FinalDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

I am new in LINQ and this could be problem for me. I am able to do that via Parallel.Foreach but I think that LINQ could be much faster. The condition is simple. Get each number from first table ("Por" column) and check in which row it belongs from second table ( "Por" >= "FirstPor" && "Por" <= "LastPor" ). I think it is simple for anybody who's working this every day. 
Yep, there is another task. The columns are STRING type, so conversion is needed in LINQ statement.

---

Yes, I have just modified my Parallel code to hybrid LINQ/Parallel and seems I am done. I used what James and Rahul wrote and put that to my code. Now, the process takes 52 seconds to estimate 421 000 rows :) It's much better.

```
public class Range
{
        public int FirstPor { get; set; }
        public int LastPor { get; set; }
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
}

var ranges = (from r in tmpDataTable.AsEnumerable()
          select new Range
                          {
                              FirstPor = Int32.Parse(r["FirstPor"] as string),
                              LastPor = Int32.Parse(r["LastPor"] as string),
                              PackageId = Int32.Parse(r["PackageId"] as string)
                          }).ToList();

Parallel.ForEach<DataRow>(dt.AsEnumerable(), row => 
{

int por = Int32.Parse(row["Por"].ToString());

                lock (locker)
                {
                    row["PackageId"] = ranges.First(range => por >= range.FirstPor && por <= range.LastPor).PackageId;
                }

                worker.ReportProgress(por);

            });
```

Comment: It is as fast as it needs to be.  Unless you're talking about thousands and thousands of rows.  In which case Linq won't help you, but a wise multithreaded strategy might.

Comment: Yep, I am working in POST office so there are a big data. My first datatable has something around 700 000 rows and second table has something around 20 000 rows, so normally when I use Parallel.Foreach it takes something around 7 minutes to get my final table. But I think that LINQ should be faster as SQL is.

Comment: If you're talking about modifying the original query to prevent this in-memory join, then possibly.  You would need to show your two queries (or equivalent, scrubbed versions) and ask how to perform your join.

Comment: @Leeon82 Linq is just a wrapper around the same mechanism that `foreach` uses which makes queries easier to write, not necessarily perform better.  I'm wondering if your logic is optimal since you're scanning every record in the second table for every record in the first table.

Comment: I am able to convert all string columns to int before the query start.

Comment: @D Stanley Is there any another solution for this logic in C#? I am open for any solution which would be faster. I know that is not a good logic ( compare each row with all rows in second table ), but in this sitaution I didn't find better logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Untested code ahead.....)

```
var newRows = FirstDatatable.Rows
             .Where(row =>SecondDatatable.Rows
                 .Any(secondRow => row["Por"] >= secondRow["FirstPor"] 
                                && row["Por"] <= secondRow["LastPor"]);

FinalDataTable.Rows.AddRange(newRows);
```

However, if speed is your real concern, my first suggestion is to dump the datatables, and use a list.  I'm gonna gues that SecondDatatable, is largely fixed, and probabaly changes less than once a day.  So, less create a nice in-memory structure for that:

```
class Range
{
     public int FirstPor {get; set;}
     public int LastPor {get; set;}
 }

 var ranges = (from r in SecondDatatable.Rows
               select new Range
                 { 
                     FirstPor = Int32.Parse(r["FirstPor"]),
                     LastPor = Int32.Parse(r["LastPor"])
                  }).ToList();
```

Then our code becomes:

```
var newRows = FirstDatatable.Rows
         .Where(row =>ranges
             .Any(range => row["Por"] >= range.FirstPor
                            && row["Por"] <= range.LastPor).ToList();
```

Which by itself should make this considerably faster.

Now, on a success, it will scan the Ranges up until it finds one that matches.  On a failure, it will have to scan the whole list before it gives up.  So, the first thing we need to do to speed this up, is to sort the list of ranges.  Then we only have to scan up to the point where the low end of the range it higher than the value we are looking for.  That should cut the processing time for those rows outside any range in half.

Comment: I think that you are almost there and this seems very clear to me. I will try that on raw data in my work. Because every day a post office produce a big datas which has to be separate in many ways. So, I am trying to figure out how to manage processes faster. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: I was thinking about the list which will hold the Ranges from SecondTable. And if we use for example all "Por" from some Range (SeconTable) then this Range will be deleted. Then the Table with Ranges will be smaller and smaller. It's an idea, didn't test this yet, but I think I have already met this solution in math on University :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
DataTable FinalDataTable = (from x in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                           from y in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                           where x.Field<int>("Por") >= y.Field<int>("FirstPor")
                                && x.Field<int>("Por") <= y.Field<int>("LastPor")
                           select x).CopyToDataTable();
```

Here is the complete [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lwd57Y), (I have tested with some sample data with your existing code and my LINQ code) you can copy paste the same in your editor and test because DotNet Fiddle is not supporting AsEnumerable.

Comment: ok, I will try that.Seems that it is needed to convert columns to int before LINQ statement.

Comment: @Leeon82 - Nope we are not converting the columns to `int`,`Field<T>` just provides the strongly typed access to our columns, as you can see in my fiddle I have defined the datatype of columns too while defining which is a good practice.